# Printing New Page with Python CGI

Tags: python, html, cgi

I'm using/learning Python to do a CGI assignment.  Basically we have to present some forms, and then based on user input, present different forms, etc.

This is my script code so far:

```
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()  # for troubleshooting
print ("Content-type: text/html\n\n")
form1 = open("html/assg5form1.html")
form2 = open("html/assg5form2.html")
form3 = open("html/assg5form3.html")
form4 = open("html/assg5form4.html")
form5 = open("html/assg5form5.html")
formstring = form1.read()
print formstring
```

The issue that I'm having is after presenting that first form, I don't know how to handle the input the user gives.  I would normally attach an action to the form and fire another script, but we are required to do all of our scripting within one file.  How can I clear out the form that I've shown and show another one?

Comment: perhaps Javascript in the head of the html file would be of help when manipulating the page layout? :)